# Is there a way to implement serialize and deserialize on trait objects with associated generic implementations?

Tags: rust, serialization, deserialization, serde

I'm working on a pre-existing project and need to make the structure Knowledge serializable and deserializable (hence the derive).

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound = "M: Matcher")]
pub struct Knowledge<M: Matcher> {
    // other fields
    pub data: GlobalVariableData,
}
```

Obviously the tricky field is data, which is a box of a trait object

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct GlobalVariableData(pub Box<dyn VariableData>);

pub trait VariableData: Debug {
    /* ... */
}
```

And most importantly, this trait has an associated generic type implementation

```
impl<T: 'static> VariableData for T
where
   T: Debug,
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Here is the problem :
To (de)serialize a trait in a way that is object safe I cannot write something like

```
pub trait VariableData: Debug + Serialize + DeserializeOwned {
    /* ... */
}
```

So how do you serialize AND deserialize a trait in a way that is object safe. The generic type implementation is also causing me more problems down the line.

I tried using [erased_serde](https://panicbit.github.io/fcm-rust/erased_serde/trait.Serialize.html). It allows for object safe serialization but not deserialization, so it couldn't really work in my case.

Then I tried [dtolnay's typetag crate](https://github.com/dtolnay/typetag) which is really amazing. It allows both serialization and deserialization of `&dyn Trait` objects.

However, it doesn't solve all my problems as [Deserialization of generic impls is not supported yet](https://github.com/dtolnay/typetag/issues/1).

My code now looks like this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound = "M: Matcher")]
pub struct Knowledge<M: Matcher> {
    // other fields
    pub data: GlobalVariableData,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct GlobalVariableData(pub Box<dyn VariableData>);

#[typetag::serde(tag = "type")]
pub trait VariableData: Debug {
    /* ... */
}

#[typetag::serde]
impl<T: 'static> VariableData for T
where
    T: Debug,
{
    /* ... */
}
```

So after using the typetag crate, my code still has an error on my generic implementation as it's just not supported:

```
impl<T: 'static> VariableData for T
```

Is there a workaround, something I haven't heard about?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a solution, aside from writing the `typetag` feature by your own. Or use an enum.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks a lot for your input. I figured that this was the case. I wouldn't mind if you could develop on the enum idea. I actually saw it around but I don't really understand how to apply it to my case ?

Comment: It's simple: replace `Box<dyn Trait>` with an enum of a closed set of options.